# mongodb - folder tree hierarchy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hierarchy

Every folder in the structure has an ancestor id list.
When I move a folder to a new parent, I have to update all children with the new ancestors:

```
// root folder
{
    id: 1,
    name: "folder 1",
    ancestorIds: []
}

    // child of folder 1
    {
        id: 2
        name: "folder 2",
        ancestorIds: [1]
    }

        // child of folder 2
        {
            id: 3
            name: "folder 3",
            ancestorIds: [1, 2]
        }

// other root folder
{
    id: 4,
    name: "folder 4",
    ancestorIds: []
}
```

Now I want to move "folder 2" (id 2) into the other root folder (folder 4, id 4).
The structure should look like this then:

```
// root folder
{
    id: 1,
    name: "folder 1",
    ancestorIds: []
}

// other root folder
{
    id: 4,
    name: "folder 4",
    ancestorIds: []
}

    // now child of folder 4
    {
        id: 2
        name: "folder 2",
        ancestorIds: [4]
    }

        // still child of folder 2, but ancestor changed!
        {
            id: 3
            name: "folder 3",
            ancestorIds: [4, 2]
        }
```

To modify the child ancestor list (id 3) correctly, I have to remove the old ancestors (id 1) and add the new ancestors (id 4).
In nodejs, it will look like this:

```
collection.update({ "ancestorIds": 2 }, { "$pullAll": { "ancestorIds": [1] } }, { multi: true }, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    collection.update({ "ancestorIds": 2 }, { "$pushAll": { "ancestorIds": [4] } }, { multi: true }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // critical error here

            throw err;
        }               
    });
});
```

If the pull request was successful, but the push failed:

the ancestorIds now have no root folder, the list is invalid!
    [2] instead of [4, 2] or [1, 2]

Can I modify the anchestor ids in a single db request?
Or is there a fundamentally different solution?

Comment: First of all, pushAll is deprecated : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/.

Comment: MongoDB tree structures info http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/